# Linux Kernel SRAM Map Into Addresses

Tags: linux-kernel, dma, texas-instruments

I have an FPGA that I am interfacing with an AM335x processor through the GPMC interface. The FPGA is basically acting as an audio codec. I am doing a DMA transfer from the SRAM into main memory. However, I need to map that memory into the address space via device tree. However, I want my module to be the only one that can access that memory (for the DMA transfer). How can I ensure that the memory is only used for the DMA transfer?

Comment: Inside the kernel you are running in prev. mode and can't protect the memory region from other access

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be DMA zones idea which might help you. https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand005.html